# reledmac: show subline number in the apparatus of manuscripts with \msdata

Tags: reledmac

I am working on a critical edition with `reledmac`/`reledpar` and I am using `\msdata` to mark sections of text witnessed by different manuscripts. I turned sublineation on with `\startsub` and `\endsub` for interpolations in my text, so I would like the apparatus of manuscripts to show subline numbers for those sections, but it seems it is not something that I can control with options or commands. Here is a MWE:

```
% !TEX encoding = utf8
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
% !TEX spellcheck = it_IT

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Junicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{italian}

\usepackage[series={A},noend,nofamiliar,noledgroup,nopbinverse]{reledmac}
\firstlinenum{1}
\linenumincrement{1}
\firstsublinenum{1}
\sublinenumincrement{1}
\Xsublinesep{}
\sublinenumberstyle{alph}

\begin{document}

\beginnumbering

\setstanzaindents{0,0}
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
\begin{stanza}
    \msdata{ABCDEF}Primo verso&
    Secondo verso&
    Terzo verso\stopmsdata&
    \startsub\msdata{EF}\emph{Primo verso interpolato}&
    \emph{Secondo verso interpolato}\stopmsdata\endsub&
    \msdata{ABCDEF}Quarto verso&
    Quinto verso&
    Sesto verso\stopmsdata\&
\end{stanza}

\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

[image: Apparatus of manuscripts without subline numbers]

I would like the second line of the apparatus to read: 3a–b Ms.] EF.

Comment: well, it is a bug, please open an issue on github repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug (more precisly, I voluntary forget to implement this feature when I start with msdata, because I wanted to have feedback before... and after that, I forget to add this feature).

The version 2.32.8, which I will send quickly on the CTAN, fixes it.

However, you should add your `\startsub` before the `&`. The handbook says

> When sub-lineation is in effect, the line number counter is frozen and
>   the sub-line counter advances instead. If one of these commands
>   appears in the middle of a line, it doesn’t take effect until the next
>   line; in other words, a line is counted as a line or sub-line
>   depending on what it started out as, even if it changes in the middle.

So, you should have

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{italian}

\usepackage[series={A},noend,nofamiliar,noledgroup,nopbinverse]{reledmac}
\firstlinenum{1}
\linenumincrement{1}
\firstsublinenum{1}
\sublinenumincrement{1}
\Xsublinesep{}
\sublinenumberstyle{alph}

    \begin{document}

    \beginnumbering

    \setstanzaindents{0,0}
    \setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
    \begin{stanza}
        \msdata{ABCDEF}Primo verso&
        Secondo verso&
        Terzo verso\stopmsdata\startsub&
        \msdata{EF}\emph{Primo verso interpolato}&
        \emph{Secondo verso interpolato}\stopmsdata\endsub&
        \msdata{ABCDEF}Quarto verso&
        Quinto verso&
        Sesto verso\stopmsdata\&
    \end{stanza}

    \endnumbering

    \end{document}
```

In your case, you get the 3,3a,3b only by hasard, as you don't indent hanging verse. Because of a misconception, in this case, the line starts when "Primo" is read by TeX, and not just after the `&`, as when the indent for hanging verse is set to a positive value. I won't correct now this bug in reledmac, because I am afraid with possible board effect. In any case, having `\startsub&` and not `&\startsub` is better, conceptually.